# Error while using apt-get install

Tags: apt

I am getting the following error whenever I try to install anything using apt-get install:

```
liam@Liam-Tosh-Linux:~$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
[sudo] password for liam: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Do post if the idea worked

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixing Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some other installation (eg via Software center) is going on on your computer you will not be able to install anything from from your terminal, So, Check if some installation is going on USC, if yes cancel it, if not restart your computer and "apt-get install" again, you will be able to install,

Comment: A restart worked